# How do I clean up desktop containing shortcuts of Home directory?

Tags: files, home-directory, delete

There are several sub-folders from Home directory which appear as shortcuts on the Desktop. If I remove them "Move to Trash" then they also remove from Home directory.

How to remove shortcuts only from Desktop ?

```
user---:~$ ls -l ~/ Desktop
ls: cannot access 'Desktop': No such file or directory
/Home/sivxx/user---/:
total 372
-rwx------  1 user--- -----    402 Sep  2  2013 desktop.ini
drwx------  3 user--- -----   4096 Jul  9 15:30 Downloads
-rw-------  1 user--- -----   3311 Nov 12  2018 key_file
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----    742 Nov 12  2018 key_file.pub
drwxr-xr-x  5 user--- -----   4096 Jul 11 14:49 Linux
drwx------  2 user--- -----   4096 Jul 20  2018 mail
drwx------  3 user--- -----   4096 Sep  2  2013 Music
drwx------  3 user--- -----   4096 Mar  5  2018 Pictures
drwx------  2 user--- -----   4096 Sep  2  2013 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwx------ 12 user--- -----   4096 Sep  2  2013 Settings
drwx------  3 user--- -----   4096 Sep  2  2013 Videos
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1157 Jul  8 16:43 vivado_19045.backup.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   2224 Jul  8 16:43 vivado_19045.backup.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----    904 Jul 10 12:20 vivado_22453.backup.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1604 Jul 10 12:20 vivado_22453.backup.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----    733 Jul 10 12:26 vivado_22944.backup.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1433 Jul 10 12:26 vivado_22944.backup.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----    733 Jul 10 12:40 vivado_24077.backup.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1433 Jul 10 12:40 vivado_24077.backup.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1393 Jul  9 13:30 vivado_4099.backup.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   2658 Jul  9 13:30 vivado_4099.backup.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----    732 Jul 11 14:45 vivado.jou
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   1507 Jul 11 14:53 vivado.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----  19358 Jul  8 16:16 vivado_pid14694.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- ----- 202004 Mar 16  2018 vivado_pid16512.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   7949 Jul  8 16:43 vivado_pid19045.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   5900 Jul 10 12:20 vivado_pid22453.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   4644 Jul 10 12:26 vivado_pid22944.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----   4720 Jul 10 12:42 vivado_pid24077.str
-rw-r--r--  1 user--- -----  11673 Jul  9 13:31 vivado_pid4099.str
drwxr-xr-x  7 user--- -----   4096 Jul 10 15:57 VivadoProjects
drwx------  3 user--- -----   4096 Jun  1  2018 WINDOWS
```

Here is the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't shortcuts but they are the *actual files*. *~/.config/user-dirs.dirs* is a file which contain details about the default user folders. It looks it was somehow messed up. Lets fix it up.

1. Create the deleted folders.

   ```
   mkdir Desktop Templates Public Documents
   ```
2. Fix *~/.config/user-dirs.dirs* file

   - Open terminal and run

     ```
     gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
     ```
   - Append correct paths of folder in front of respective folder name so that it looks like

     ```
     XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
     XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
     XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
     XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
     XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
     XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
     XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
     XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
     ```

     and save the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
3. Now navigate to *Desktop* to see if it's empty (since the folders are created recently and no file was added to that).